# Is there a way to remove a turtle from the screen?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have the following code:

```
answer = "ABC"
flag.goto(-999, -999)
while (answer.lower != 'y' or answer.lower != 'n'):
    print("You got the flag! Free play(y/n)?")
    answer = input("")
    if answer.lower == 'y':
        pass
    if answer.lower == 'n':
        return None
```

I am trying to remove the turtle called `flag`, through adding it to a list then deleting it with `del(testlist[0])`, but it didn't work.
The output is:

```
You got the flag! Free play(y/n)?
y
You got the flag! Free play(y/n)?
n
You got the flag! Free play(y/n)?
```

Comment: Please, add some other tags.

Comment: `answer.lower` is a reference to a method, and will *never* be equal to the strings you're comparing it to.  `answer.lower()` is what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing as the title and text ask one thing, 
while your example code and output show something completely different.

Let's address this question:

> Is there a way to remove a turtle from the screen?

Generally `turtle.hideturtle()` will do what you want.  The only way to *dispose* of turtles once created is via a `screen.clear()` which will destroy *all* of them.

(The variable `turtle` above needs to be set to an instance of `Turtle()` and the variable `screen` needs to be set to the singular instance of `Screen()`.

Answer (score 0):

> You can get a better view on the Visibility of turtles from this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#visibility).

Basically, you can use either `turtle.hideturtle()` or `turtle.ht()` to make a turtle invisible.
 But, that does not mean that the turtle is removed, and so it still takes up memory.

You *can* call `turtle.Screen.clear()`, but that resets *everything*, even the things you might want to keep.

If I were in a situation where I want to delete turtles instead of hiding them because doing that over and over again will take up too much memory, I'd simply hide the turtle, and when the program need another turtle, instead of creating another one, simply unhide the hidden turtle to be used again.

Comment: @GhostCat Wow, I didn't know that! Thanks for informing me. I wonder why I haven't noticed your comment...

Comment: I guess occasionally the notification system just doesnt work. Or you the notification shows up, but you overlook it. Just happens from time to time.